# PUT Request showing in logs

Tags: rest, put, restful-url

Not sure if I'm missing something here, but every site on RESTful design states that updates should be done via a PUT request. I've been doing that, but noticed that the parameters are being put in the URL (unlike a POST request) which means they will show in the logs.

So if a user updates their password, the plain text password will show in the log. This doesn't seem right. What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it is required for PUT to have params in the URL to consider it as restful.
You should have the following or something similar

```
HTTPS PUT  /users/<userid>/password
Body: {password: abcd}
```

Comment: Now looking at it a bit more closely I think this is a strange issue in PHPStorm REST Test tool. I tried a PUT request from a standard web browser and it doesn't put the params in the url. When I make the same call from the REST tool it puts the params in the url for some reason.